# android action bar overlay issue for Up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overlay

I have been following the tutorial @

[Add Up Button for Low-level Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) for a `display_message_activity` (I also set the action bar as transparent), and then tried to [Specify Layout Top-margin](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html) using `?attr/actionBarSize`, but the action bar ("My Message") seems covers the entire message ("Hello World") as follows

[image]

So I wonder how to solve the issue? The following is `activity_display_message.xml` in `layout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" 
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

cheers

Comment: You use a transparant ActionBar, in which case the Views will start at the same height as the Actionbar. If you don't want that, don't use the transparant ActionBar. Instead, you might want to change the background color of the ActionBar.

Comment: @fifarunnerr even if I use `orange` background color as I defined in the `color.xml`, the message is still covered entirely by the action bar, so any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: You probably enabled [Overlay Mode](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html). Disable overlay mode, and then it should work.

Comment: @fifarunnerr yes, I enabled the `overlay` mode, but I also use `?attr/actionBarSize` to try to make the `textView` remains below the action bar, but it seems that it did not work